# Getter and setter with inline instruction

Tags: delphi

Does Delphi inline by default getter and setter or we must ourselves manually add "inline" at the end of the getter/setter functions ?

Comment: A getter or setter function need not be lightweight.

Comment: I agree, but If I add "inline" in front of my getter/setter function, does it's matter ?

Comment: I think so, but there is never any guarantee. (I was about to have a look at the docs, but unfortunately the docwiki is down again.) Also by "in front of..." I suppose you mean to the *right* of the getter/setter declaration?

Comment: thanks andreas, yes I mean to the right of the getter/setter :)

Comment: Properties are handled effectively by a pre-processor which replaces the property access with the getter or setter, and then compiles that. So yeah, I think they will be unlined just the same as a function call.